# C# ASP.NET and javascript onclientclick function not found

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a link button and JavaScript setup like so

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbutton" 
                CssClass="Button" 
                OnClientClick="javascript:PlayVideo();" 
                runat="server">Play Video</asp:LinkButton>

<script type="text/javascript">
    funtion PlayVideo(){
        $('#ctl00_EFlyerCPH_EFlyerPart_ytapiplayer2').show();
        $('#ctl00_EFlyerCPH_EFlyerPart_imageID').hide();
    }
</script>
```

but when I click on my button I get an error saying

PlayVideo is not defined...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your Script defined before the Link ?

Comment: You want

OnClientClick="PlayVideo()"

The "javascript:" protocol is for where URLs are expected, like href.  Don't think it's the issue here though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have:

```
funtion PlayVideo(){
```

`function` is spelled wrong.  It should be:

```
function PlayVideo(){
```

Comment: Darn it. Quicker than me! +1

Comment: Thanks, I will be able to accept your answer in 9 minutes.